# Frequencies of current harmonics 1 phase diode bridge rectifier

Tags: diodes, power-electronics, bridge-rectifier, single-phase

I was wondering what would be the frequency of the current harmonics at the input of a 1phase diode bridge rectifier. My believe is that it should be 60Hz for Is1, 180Hz for Is3, essentially every 60Hz for an odd component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impulses (the current surges) will correlate with ANY time_function.

Correlation is what the maths of Fourier Analysis and Fourier Transform use.

If you use LONG SERIES OF TIME SAMPLES, then the stored_energy reduces the correlation efficiency with arbitrary time_functions, and repetitive time_functions have stronger correlation, and we chose to declare "AHHH Harmonics are present".

The fast edges of the rectified current surges (low microseconds of turnon time, unless you insert resistors or inductors) will correlate with any time_function. And the repetitive nature of the 60Hz pulses are best (mathematically) correlated with repetitive waveforms.

The imbalanced nature of the current surges will correlate with both even and odd "harmonics".

Answer (score 1):

- Consider approximations that you have low ripple voltage Vpp< 10% Vavg.
- Then a current pulse per cycle must Ipk  must be 10x the average current in <10% of the T cycle time to maintain this average current load.
- So you must realize a narrow pulse that rises fast and tapers off slow must have at least all the harmonics of the fundamental up to the 5th harmonics at least and attenuated up towards the 10th harmonic. There will be more below some threshold such as -20 dB of pk.
- f-3db=0.35/Tr holds true from 10~90% rise time , Tr for the -3dB BW of spectrum.
- Odd harmonics only hold true for Square waves and their integrals like Triangle waves.